# set -xv behavior in ksh vs bash

Tags: ksh, debugging, function

Normally I like to have all of the debug output of a script go to a file, so I will have something like:

```
exec 2> somefile
set -xv
```

This work very will in bash, but I have noticed in ksh it behaves differently when it comes to functions.  I noticed when I do this in ksh, the output does not show the function trace, only that the function was called.

When doing some additional testing, I noticed the behavior also depends on how the function was declared, if I use the ksh syntax of:

```
function doSometime {....}
```

All I see is the function call, however if declare the function using the other method, eg

```
doSomething() {....}
```

The trace works as expected.  Is it possible to get `set -xv` to work the same with both types of function declarations?  I tried `export SHELLOPTS` and that did not make a difference either.

I am using ksh93 on Solaris 11.

Comment: Why do you use the non-standard definition syntax in the first place?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273474/kornshell-set-x-debug-flag-globally

Comment: According to tldp bash guide, `name() {}` is portable ans according to C style.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh **DO NOT USE CODE MARKUP FOR THINGS THAT ARE NOT CODE**. This is not the first time you've been told that.

Comment: @Gilles , I try to read carefuly all of FAQ, thank you for your hint.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh also, please be careful and don't introduce grammatical mistakes [when you edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/162316/2). In English, _I_ should _always_ be capitalized when it's used as a [personal pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_pronoun).

Comment: @terdon  , If you have more links spesially for review you make me happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Functions  defined by the **function** *name* syntax and called by name execute in the same process as the caller and
>          share all files and present working directory with the caller.  **Traps caught by the caller are reset  to  their
>          default  action inside the function.**

Whereas

> Functions  defined  with the *name*() syntax and functions defined with the function name syntax that are invoked
>          with the .  special built-in are executed in the caller's environment and **share all variables  and  traps  with
>          the caller.**

The solution is to not use the `function` keyword; stick to the standard form of function definitions.

Alternatively, if you're only interested in a few functions, `typeset -tf fname` will just trace the function `fname` (if it was defined with the `function` keyword).

To stop tracing: `typeset +tf fname`

To trace all such functions in ksh93: `typeset -tf $(typeset +f)`

To see which functions are traced: `typeset +tf`

To stop tracing all functions: `typeset +tf $(typeset +tf)`